# unable to set foreign key checks =0 from terminal

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, terminal, centos

I am trying to run the following code from a linux (CentOS 7) terminal:

```
mysql -u root -p -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0"; mysql -u root -p -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME  -u root -p| while read table; do mysql -u root -p -e "truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done;
```

But it apparently does not process the set foreign key checks command because in response I get:

```
ERROR 1701 (42000) at line 1: Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`atest`.`PARTICIPANT_2`, CONSTRAINT `FK_0a036647645f4e5e950470cb2dc` FOREIGN KEY (`PARTICIPANT_ACT_HJID`) REFERENCES `atest`.`ACT` (`HJID`))
```

Also, it continues to ask me for the password.  I expect it to ask 3 times for the password, but not to repeat the three requests again and again.  How can I change my code above to get it to run correctly, and with a minimal number of requests for password?

**EDIT:**

The following modification appears to be asking for the password for EVERY table in the loop. There are 500+ tables. How can I fix this so it only asks for the password a couple times?

```
mysql -u root -p -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -u root -p -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table" atest; done;
```

Comment: MySQL is processing the SET statement. But the way you have it coded, it performs that SET statement in a *separate* session. It looks like you are wanting to make that variable change in the *same* session that performs the `TRUNCATE TABLE`. It's possible to run multiple statements. (See my answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `foreign_key_checks` is a session variable, it's in effect only for the current session, until it's changed, or until the session ends.

You are creating multiple database session, each new session starts with it's own `foreign_key_checks` variable, set to the default (inherited from the global setting). (I'm not going to mention how you change the default, because you do not really want to go there.)

One option would be to perform the `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` statement in the *same* session as the `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement.

Use a semicolon as a statement separator. As a demonstration of running two statements:

```
mysql -u me -pXX -e "show variables like 'foreign%'; show variables like '%packet%';"
```

Comment: Thank you.  So how does this apply to the code in my OP?

Comment: **`-e "set foreign_key_checks = 0; truncate table $table;"`**

Comment: `mysql -u root -p -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -u root -p -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table" atest; done;` appears to be asking for the password for EVERY table in the loop.  There are 500+ tables.  How can I fix this so it only asks for the password a couple times?

Comment: Thank you and +1.  I see you answered the other part of the question elsewhere: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27933828/how-do-i-loop-from-terminal-without-excessive-password-requests/27934005#27934005