# How do I loop from terminal without excessive password requests

Tags: mysql, sql, linux, terminal, centos

When running the following MySQL code from a Linux (CentOS 7) terminal, the following command appears to be asking for the password for EVERY table in the loop. There are 500+ tables. It is not reasonable for me to type in a password 500+ times.  How can I fix the code below so that it only asks for the password a couple times?

```
mysql -u root -p -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -u root -p -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done;
```

### Edit

Is there a way to do this without having to put the password in the command line logs?

Answer (score 0):

Put the password after the p (no space), say your password is PASSWORD

```
mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -Nse 'show tables' DATABASE_NAME | while read table; do mysql -u root -pPASSWORD -e "SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0; truncate table $table" DATABASE_NAME; done;
```

Comment: Technically, that works, but the terminal replied by stating itself the concern that I had also: `Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.`

Answer (score 0):

Consider re-writing this, so that it only uses two database sessions. One to produce a list of statements to execute into a file, and second (single) to process the statements. There's potential for something to go wrong with the first query session, so I'd be careful to separate them into two tasks.

In the first session, suppress the formatting, and redirect stdout to a file

```
SELECT 'set foreign_key_checks = 0;' AS stmt

SELECT CONCAT('TRUNCATE TABLE `',t.table_schema,'`.`',table_name,'`;') AS stmt
  FROM information_schema.tables t
 WHERE t.table_schema = 'mydatabase'
 ORDER BY t.table_name ;
```

Verify that the file contains what you want.

Then (another useless use of cat) pipe the contents of that file into mysql

```
cat myfile | mysql -u me -p --database mydatabase
```